# How to determine the area of a circular sector

Tags: geometry

How do you solve for the area of a circular sector if the arc length is $4\pi$ and the radius of the circle is $9$?

Comment: The circumference of the circle is $18\pi$. The arc length is $2/9$ of that, so surely the area should be $2/9$ of the area of the circle?

Comment: I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To find the area of a circular sector, use the formula $$\frac{θ}{360} * \pi r^2,$$ where $r$ is your radius and $\theta$ is the central angle in degrees. To find the central angle, measure the angle between both radii in the sector. To prove that you got the correct area, use $$\frac{(A_{\text{sec}} * 360)}{\pi r^2},$$ where $A_{\text{sec}}$ is the area of your circular sector. Your answer should be your central angle, or $\theta$.

The apothem and sagitta are irrelevant in this problem, so you do not need to worry about them. But just for curiosity, the sagitta it the height of the triangular portion formed in a circular sector and the apothem is the distance from the circumference to the equal chord length that forms a polygon throughout the circle. The shape formed is generally an $8$-gon to a $12$-gon.